# Failing IF in a WHILE loop in BASH script that checks for open 22 ports

Tags: shell-script, scripting, nc

Im trying to create a rather basic script to run through a list of servers and check if the SSH port is open using `nc`. I've tried a few different ways, but can't seem to get this to work. I am definitely not great at any type of scripting.

Here is the script. I just want it to perform an action if it sees "succeeded" in the response from the `nc` command in `OPEN`.

```
while read SERVER
do
OPEN=$(nc -z -v -w5 $SERVER 22)
echo $SERVER
   if [[ $OPEN = *"suc"* ]];
    then
        echo "Found SSH open on $SERVER"
    else
        echo "No open ports on $SERVER!"    
   fi
done < server.txt
```

The list of servers is in the `server.txt` file that is referenced at the end on the script.

Here is the response that I get. I not

```
nc: connect to 10.10.51.55 port 22 (tcp) failed: No route to host
10.10.51.55
No open ports on test1!
Connection to 10.10.51.65 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
10.10.50.65
No open ports in test2!
```

It give me the "No open ports on $SERVER" no matter what.

I thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Did you actually check the value of `OPEN`? you're capturing standard output - but I suspect the `... succeeded!` message from `nc` is on the standard error stream

Comment: I hope the issue with ur server.txt try giving ipaddress.

Comment: @steeldriver thank you my friend -- you have helped me. That was it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notes, too long for a comment.

1. `server.txt` could better be named `server-list` or `servers.txt` if you wish.
2. Use lower case variable names like, avoid `SERVER` and alike, could better be named `server_ip` anyways, because it is unclear if you use host names or IPs.
3. Double quote all non-integer-number variables like `"$server_ip"`.
4. Use a direct `if` statement instead of variable `$OPEN` with a redirection to the black hole (`/dev/null`).

---

Rewritten based on above:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r server_ip; do

    if nc -z -v -w5 "$server_ip" 22 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Found SSH port open on $server_ip."
    else
        echo "Did not find open SSH port on $server_ip." >&2
    fi

done < server-list
```

Answer (score 3):

The most simple solution seems to be:

```
if nc -z -v -w5 $SERVER 22 >/dev/null 2>&1;
then
    echo "Found SSH open on $SERVER"
else
    echo "No open ports on $SERVER!"    
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `nc` writes to standard error when outputting diagnostic messages, while a command substitution only captures standard output.

You also should be using `==` in `[[ ... ]]`. Variable expansions should be quoted and ideally, you'd be using `printf` to output variable data.

This means that your code could look like

```
while IFS= read -r SERVER do
    OPEN=$( nc -z -v -w5 "$SERVER" 22 2>&1 )
    if [[ "$OPEN" == *succ* ]]; then
        printf 'Found SSH open on %s\n' "$SERVER"
    else
        printf 'No open ports on %s!\n' "$SERVER"    
    fi
done <server.txt
```

or

```
while IFS= read -r SERVER do
    OPEN=$( nc -z -v -w5 "$SERVER" 22 2>&1 )
    case "$OPEN" in
        *succ*) printf 'Found SSH open on %s\n' "$SERVER" ;;
        *)      printf 'No open ports on %s!\n' "$SERVER"  ;;
    esac
done <server.txt
```

Or, you could just use the exit status of `nc`:

```
while IFS= read -r SERVER do
    if nc -z -v -w5 "$SERVER" 22 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf 'Found SSH open on %s\n' "$SERVER"
    else
        printf 'No open ports on %s!\n' "$SERVER"
    fi
done <server.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips and also the different ways of completing my task. This has helped me through teaching as well.

Comment: Why should they be using `==`? That's just an alias for `=`. In `[[...]]`, there's no need to distinguish between assignment and comparison (well, pattern matching here), there's no need for `==`. You may be confusing with `(( a = b ))` (assignment) vs `(( a == b ))` (arithmetic comparison).

Comment: Beware the behaviour of `read SERVER` is dependent on the current value of `$IFS`. For instance, with `IFS=m`, `read server` on `google.com` stores `google.co` into `$server`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm using `==` in `[[ ... ]]`, and I'm only ever using `[[ ... ]]` when I need to, e.g. for pattern matching.  It's personal style. The `read` issue will be fixed ASAP.